# Is it possible to do an advance search on comments?

Tags: support, comments, search

I will explain the reason for my search, maybe someone can help me find the said comment:

I remember having seen a comment with a link to a website of a scientist explaining why the Halting problem was not as important to him as it was to the CS community, and was a bit of an artificial problem. I would like to find this link, however I could not find how to make a search on something else than posts.

Is it possible to search keywords in comments?

Comment: I think you're going to have to use SEDE. There's usually people On meta chat https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1223 that can help.

Comment: Other than that, try to see if you can manipulate an non-SE engine to find comments.

Comment: Oh nice! I'll try to play a bit with it!

Comment: Thank you for the info!